# Android-like Zoom on Windows Chrome with only keyboard and mouse?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Ctrl+wheel changes the whole page's layout at each zoom level, so for a complicated website, ctrl+wheel is very choppy and slow. And in most cases, that isn't even necessary, because I just want to see a part of the page (such as a small image or letters like the Chinese letters) bigger, not the whole page. On Android, I could just pinch-to-zoom on that part, but I can't find a way to do that on Windows Chrome.

I mean, without a touchscreen or a touch pad. With a touch pad, Windows Chrome zooms in/out exactly like the Android Chrome, but my desktop does not have a touch pad.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [mouse-pinch-to-zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mouse-pinch-to-zoom/pffiadlahfhoniddbipeiiohjnlongfi). This is a Chrome plugin. You can easily install it through Chrome webstore.
After installed, you can use Alt+Scroll to do "*Android-like Zoom*" (*pinch-to-zoom*).

Also it's open-sourced on Github: [nizioleque/mouse-pinch-to-zoom](https://github.com/nizioleque/mouse-pinch-to-zoom)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1122897)

Comment: At the very least you should descibe *how* to use the software to solve the problem as asked in the question. [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). How does this tool achieve what is asked? How do you use it? How do you set it up?

Comment: Thanks! I have added some relevant information