# Chrome, pinch zoom using mouse on PC?

Tags: google-chrome, zoom

Sometimes I want to zoom in to a specify portion of the page for better reading.

This can be easily done using a trackpad and pinch zoom.

Can I also pinch zoom when using a mouse?

Comment: ctrl + wheel should work as John mentioned in his answer at the end.

Comment: you can use [mouse-pinch-to-zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mouse-pinch-to-zoom/pffiadlahfhoniddbipeiiohjnlongfi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android-like Zoom on Windows Chrome with only keyboard and mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/1448964/android-like-zoom-on-windows-chrome-with-only-keyboard-and-mouse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I also pinch zoom when using a mouse?

No. Not with your vanilla two to three / wheel button mouse.

I believe pinch zoom has been back ported to track pads after appearing in phones and tablets.

But there are alternative accessibility facilities such as enlargement lenses since earlier than pinching appearing in phones.

You can use those, they will vary depending on the particular OS you are using.

You can as well pick a convertible laptop - tablet choice, when buying a new device. Those's screens might be likely *pinchable*.

I suppose an advanced mouse would help your case.

Even a vanilla mouse with a wheel would be enough if the particular OS allows to zoom in and out via programming the wheel for such thing. Or a combined gesture click + use wheel.